# What is the variable declaration "var (name, categoryId) = object" called in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm using .NET 4.8 and declare a record with a Deconstructor:

```
public record Product
{
    public string Name { get;  }
    public int CategoryId { get;  }

    public Product(string name, int categoryId)
      => (Name, CategoryId) = (name, categoryId);

    public void Deconstruct(out string name, out int categoryId)
      => (name, categoryId) = (Name, CategoryId);
}
```

Then I use the following code which is compiled and it works fine :

```
var product = new Product("VideoGame", 1);
var (name, categoryId) = product;
string s = name;
int i = categoryId;
```

While this code doesn't work an error is generated:

> "Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApp4.Product' to 'System.Tuple<string, int>'"):

```
var product = new Product("VideoGame", 1);
Tuple<string, int> t = product;
string s = t.Item1;
int i = t.Item2;
```

The declaration `var (name, categoryId)` is not clear. What is it?
What is the type of this variable? How is this construction called in the specification?
Is that an auto-generated type behind the scene and the `name` and the `categoryId` are its properties?

Comment: That is called [Deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct). FYI, In a `record`, you don't need to write a `Deconstruct` method since it is generated for you, unless you need to customize it. Your `record` could be rewritten as `public record Product(string Name, int CategoryId);` and it will mean the exact same thing

Comment: `var` can infer the type automatically. It is not pointing to any particular type though

Comment: If you don't like `var (name, categoryId) = product;`, then you can also write `(string name, int categoryId) = product;` Here you see directly the type of your variables.

Comment: I thought that [`record` types were a new feature of c# 9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types) and that [c# 9.0 was only supported on .net 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version). Am I missing something? How are you getting this to compile using .NET 4.8?

Comment: @Igor: I'm surprised too. I double checked the project target framework and it is 4.8, but the compiler doesn't know what is "init" in the same time. I early tried to install .NET 5 on my machine, it completed installation but .NET 5 is not available in project's options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the syntax

```
var (name, categoryId) = product;
```

is a **deconstruction** - it is NOT an assignment to a tuple.

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct)

> Starting with C# 7.0, you can retrieve multiple elements from a tuple or retrieve multiple field, property, and computed values from an object in a single deconstruct operation. When you deconstruct a tuple, you assign its elements to individual variables. When you deconstruct an object, you assign selected values to individual variables.

Ignoring `Deconstruct` for a moment, any tuple can be deconstructed into individual variables, provided that sufficient variables (or the discard, `_`) be provided to accomodate the tuple.

e.g.

```
(string name, int categoryId) = ("Hello", 123);
```

Assigns *"Hello"* to `name`, and *123* to `categoryId`

All of the below are equivalent

```
(string name, int categoryId) = ("Hello", 123); // Types of tuple match position vars
(var name, var categoryId) = ("Hello", 123); // Type variable types are inferred
var (name, categoryId) = ("Hello", 123);
```

Similarly, by providing suitable `Deconstruct` overloads or extension methods for your own classes / records, you can assign multiple variables to the `out` parameters of the matched `Deconstruct` method:

```
var (name, categoryId) = Product;
```

which tells the compiler to look for an appropriate `Deconstruct` overload for `Product`.
In this case, because you're using `var` type inference for all the deconstructed, the deconstructor must have 2 parameters (of any type, which will be inferred).

There are some other nuances happening here.

Firstly, as you've seen, you can declare many different [Deconstructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct) for your `Product` record, as long as the signatures of the deconstructions differ.

The (value) tuple syntax

```
public void Deconstruct(out string name, out int categoryId)
    => (name, categoryId) = (Name, CategoryId);
```

is just a convenient short hand for

```
public void Deconstruct(out string name, out int categoryId)
{
    name = Name;
    categoryId = CategoryId;
}
```

When you make the following assignment:

```
 var (name, categoryId) = product;
```

1. An appropriate deconstruct overload is located for `Product`, in this case, because you're using `var` type inference, the deconstructor must have 2 parameters (but any type).
2. The out variables are then [assigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-assignment-and-deconstruction) to your deconstruct variables, which you've also named `string name` and `int categoryId`.

Although you can't deconstruct directly INTO a `System.ValueTuple` or `System.Tuple`, you can deconstruct FROM both

```
var (name, categoryId) = Tuple.Create("Hello", 123); // Old Heap tuples

var (name, categoryId) = ("Hello", 123); // Newer value tuples
```

One of the major uses of Deconstruction is for short hand notation during [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/csharp-8-0-pattern-matching-in-csharp-8-0#expressing-patterns), where you can quickly reason over the type and properties:

e.g. instead of

```
var result = product switch
{
  Product x when x.CategoryId == 3 => "You've got a category 3 product",
  Product x when string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Name) => "That product looks broken",
  _ => "Just a standard product"
};
```

You can instead deconstruct and / or discard as necessary:

```
var result2 = product switch
{
  var (_, cat) when cat == 3 => "You've got a category 3 product",
  var (str, _) when string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) => "That product looks broken",
  _ => "Just a standard product"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is called just like that `deconstruction` (or `unpackage` like in python). In general this is only a feature that came out in C# 7.0 just to save you time by not declaring all the tuple and then access its items one by one. For more information look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct).